# Linux awk command to retrieve first and last row

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to retrieve the first and last row of **awk** command, but I'm not able to. Where I'm making mistakes.

```
egrep 'updateAll|update-mgr|Startup REX|configd.*UnitProperty updated' $LOG | \
  awk 'NR == 1{print $1" "$2" "$3} NR == $#{print $1" "$2" "$3}'

awk: cmd. line:2: NR == 1{print $1" "$2" "$3} NR == $#{print $1" "$2" "$3}
awk: cmd. line:2:                                    ^ syntax error
```

I expect first row and last row form the output of `grep` command.

Comment: `$#` has no meaning in awk ... and if it understood the bashism it still wouldn't do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Btw - most of the time when you use grep & awk in one command you're doing it wrong ;)

```
awk '
{  
    if ($0~/updateAll|update-mgr|Startup REX|configd.*UnitProperty updated/) {
       c++
       l=$0
       if(c==1){print}       
    }
}
END{print l}
'  $LOG
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NR == 1` to get the first line, and `END` to get the last line.

Having this input:

```
$ echo -e '1 a v\n2 b w\n3 c x\n4 d y\n5 e z'
1 a v
2 b w
3 c x
4 d y
5 e z
```

we can parse it using this `awk` command:

```
$ echo -e '1 a v\n2 b w\n3 c x\n4 d y\n5 e z' | awk 'NR == 1 { print $2; } END { print $2; }'
a
e
```

Answer (score 0):

@tink solution is correct. I just wish to add that: .

Using variable `l` is bad practice, since it can be mistaken to `1` or `I` depending on the current font.

The default match pattern can be extracted as filter pattern for record processing.

So @tink solution becomes:

```
awk '
/updateAll|update-mgr|Startup REX|configd.*UnitProperty updated/ {  
    c++;
    lastLine = $0;
    if(c == 1){print}       
}
END{print lastLine}
'  $LOG
```